# mod_rewrite - set _GET var from path

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How to set _GET var from path?

## .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^api\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/_api/([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /_api/?v=%1&k=%2 [L]
```

## URL

```
http://api.domain.com/get_var1/get_var2/
```

## code

```
echo "_GET\n";
print_r($_GET);
```

## result

```
_GET
Array
(
    [v] => 
)
(
    [k] => 
)
```

## what the result should be

```
_GET
Array
(
    [v] => get_var1
)
(
    [k] => get_var2
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for URL of type:

```
http://api.domain.com/get_var1/get_var2/
```

Do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^api\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/_api/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/])/$   /_api/?v=$1&k=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /_api/?v=%1 [L]
```

to :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /_api/?v=$1 [L]
```

actually the %1 is the variable generated from the RewriteCond directive not the RewriteRule one

Comment: have updated my question.. I need to set multiple `_GET` vars

Comment: @clarkk can't you split the in the php script ? especially useful for multiple elements in the path